# HTML shown in browser when using back button

Tags: php, laravel, apache

This is kind of weird. I upgraded a Laravel 5.8 application to version 6.x. On an Apache web server with PHP7.3 when I use the browser back button, the plain HTML code is shown in the browser. If I reload the page it all is OK.

On the exact same server I am also running the 5.8 version, and there the back button works fine. Therefor my best guess is that this is an issue with Laravel 6.x

But I cannot find any article about this, so hopefully some one on here can help me out.

In Chrome no error message, just the plain HTML code in view. But in Firefox, I am getting this error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: you need improve the answer, not just versions, show us some code or a simplified version of your problem

Comment: What code? From the controller, from the view and what. Cause if I cannot put my finger on it, I would not know where to begin. By the way, it's in every page, so every view and every method

Comment: Can you check the headers of the response being sent to the browser? Is the content type correct?

Comment: That's the thing, when the developers console is open, all works fine, but when its closed the problem occurs. With development console open the content type is `text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: @AhmedShefeer, in Firefox I got some more info. If I hit the back button, the content type is `application/json` till I reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have figured it out... When there is a jQuery Ajax call on a page that does a POST or a GET to it's own and data type is set to json, the page's header changes to `application/json`. It's weird that this was not an issue in Laravel 5.8, but it is all of a sudden in version 6.x

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/page',
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content')},
    dataType: 'json',
    formData: { media_folder_id: $("#media-folder-id").val() },
    context: $("#fileupload")[0]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

check for any link tag in the head section of your  tag and remove any

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#" id="example"/>`

with `href="#"`

Comment: Replace it with the same? I am not getting this....